# How to add a command/flag in kubernetes deployment using json patch command?

Tags: json, kubernetes

We have an Kubernetes deployment and we would like to add a insecure commnand/flag in below manifest using something like below command

```
kubectl patch deploy xxxx --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "value":"nginx"}]'
```

Please help how to achieve this?

**Current manifest**

```
spec:
  .
  .
  template:
    .
    . 
    spec:
      .
      .
      containers:
      - command:
        - argocd-server
```

**New Manifest**

```
spec:
  .
  .
  template:
    .
    . 
    spec:
      .
      .
      containers:
      - command:
        - argocd-server
        - --insecure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
kubectl patch deployment xxxx --type='json' -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/command", "value": ["argocd-server", "--insecure"]}]'
```

and verify the `command`

```
kubectl get deployment xxxx  -o=json | jq '.spec.template.spec.containers[0].command'
```

output

```
[
  "argocd-server",
  "--insecure"
]
```